# How to disable RSS in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, iis, rss

my web site  is a template, it has web.config. 
how to disable its RSS in this web

i am using vendor's web site, i find web.config only have an applicationfoldername to set for RSS when i read the comment

however, no enable or disable option for RSS, how can i know where to disable RSS

it has RSS_Feed class in code directory
and RSS_result in xslt directory
and  in web.config for RSS

Comment: Your question is too short. Please explain what are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look for something like this on the html template and remove it (don't make a literal search of the entire tag since title and href will be different)

```
<link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" title="RSS" href="url" />
```

Comment: after searched rss word in web.config, no this line

Comment: @OvO: not on web.config, look for it on the html